# AWS RDSDataService times out whereas external mysql package works

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-rds

I have a AWS Lambda (Node.js) talking to an Aurora database. Both belong to the same VPC, with internet access enabled via subnet. The RDS cluster also has a inbound rule that allows traffic from the VPC, used for the Lambda (which should be the same VPC). To my surprise, I found that the `RDSDataService` from `AWS-SDK` fails to connect to the database, whereas when I use [`mysql` pacakge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql), it works. Following are the 2 code snippets.

I would like it very much to use AWS-SDK, as that will reduce the deployment bundle size, as I don't have to include that in the bundle that at all. Is there anyway to achieve that?

**Failed attempt to use `RDSDataService`**

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const rdsData = new AWS.RDSDataService({
    params: {
        dbClusterOrInstanceArn: 'rds.cluster.arn',
        awsSecretStoreArn: 'rds.cluster.secret.arn',
        database: 'mydb'
    },
    endpoint: 'mydb.endpoint'
});

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
        rdsData.executeSql({
            dbClusterOrInstanceArn: 'rds.cluster.arn',
            awsSecretStoreArn: 'rds.cluster.secret.arn',
            database: 'mydb',
            sqlStatements: "select 1 + 1 as result;"
        }, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            const response = {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
            };
            resolve(response);
        });
    } catch (er) {
        reject(er);
    }
});
```

**Working implementation using `mysql`**

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'mydb.endpoint',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    port: 3306,
    database: 'mydb',
    debug: false
});

connection.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) context.fail();
    else {
        connection.query('select 1 + 1 as result', function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) throw error;
            resolve('The solution is: ' + JSON.stringify(results, undefined, 2));
        });
    }
});
connection.end();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, Data API is not yet available for my region. The supported regions are listed here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html#data-api.regions